# Restore Windows 8 Appstore

Tags: windows-8, restore

I accidentally deleted my Windows 8 App's including the App Store. I searched the whole web for how to restore the App Store without setting up a new system. Haven't found any solutions yet. Does anybody know how to do that?

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You searched the WHOLE web and you couldn't find anything to try? I have trouble believing that. :)  How did you delete them exactly?  Have you tried using [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) to go back before you deleted the files? What *have* you tried already?

Comment: Well not the whole world, but I searched with google to page 43 or so :D. Tried System Restore, did restore everything except the apps -.- Also I tried this one http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/19529-store-restore-missing-tile-start-screen-windows-8-a.html every else article just wanted to pin the icon back to the start screen.

Comment: Oh, and the way I deleted them: I erased the programs folder :D, well actually it wasn't me more my fried who wanted to play a prank on me - which I gotta say did work pretty well :D

Comment: Only solution is to refresh your system. Next  time don't let friends use your computer as an administrator